# Always recurring Errors while Installing/Uninstalling

Tags: angular, npm

No matter what i am installing with npm, these Errors always show up:

```
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/home/angular-workspace/highcharts-angular-master/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:209:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 5.0.0-27-generic
gyp ERR! command "/home/.nvm/versions/node/v12.10.0/bin/node" "/home/angular-workspace/highcharts-angular-master/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd /home/angular-workspace/highcharts-angular-master/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v12.10.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
Build failed with error code: 1
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@4.10.0 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.10.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

What am I doing wrong? what is the problem here? I tried uninstalling and installing everything again but this didn't work either.The Errors even show up while uninstalling something.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried clearing your cache of npm you do that with this `npm cache clean`

and as the last sentence it says this is probably not a problem with npm. so i don't know is this the entire stack/log??

or it might an error with high carts because i see it occurring in the stack twice

Comment: Tried cache clean which didn't work... You're probably right that it is a high charts problem but i didn't find a solution yet.

Comment: i think it is an problem with your dependencies but i am not sure have never worked with high charts